# Where's the error in the faulty sentence 有人认为，过年觉得没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系?

Tags: grammar

The HSK6 Standard Course workbook has the following "faulty sentence" exercise (chapter 14, page 115; [photo of original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiEoO.jpg); OCR by Yandex):

> 19. A "糖瓜"是这里过年流行的美食。
>     B **有人认为，过年觉得没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系**。
>     C 老汉不善言辞，但讲起制作松鼠鱼繁复的过程，他立刻滔滔不绝。
>     D 这个徽州女人和她不太会讲话的儿子，把这家豆腐房经营得红红火火。

The answer is B with no explanation given.  This sentence was asked about at [HiNative](https://hinative.com/questions/23001927), where a user there deleted either 认为 or 觉得 from the original sentence.  No explanation was given, but it looks like their interpreting 觉得 as functioning as a verb performed by the subject 有人, which I don't believe is correct because...

The sentence takes the form:

> 有人认为，X。
> Some people believe: X.

wherein X is a statement for which there exists people that believe it is true.  We might encounter such sentences like:

> 有人认为不吃早餐就可以减少热量的摄入。  ([source](https://www.sohu.com/a/545306606_120854882))
> Some people believe: not eating breakfast can reduce calorie absorption.

Importantly, 不吃早餐 is not interpreted as a verb phrase with the subject 有人, but as a noun phrase (the act of not eating breakfast), and is the subject of the second clause.  Thus I interpret the "faulty sentence" as:

> 有人认为，A也许跟B有很大关系。
> Some people believe: A might be strongly related with B.

wherein

> A = 过年觉得没意思 = the act of feeling bored during Chinese New Year
> B = 年味逐年冷淡 = the Spring Festival atmosphere cooling down over the years.

Hence...

**Question**: Where's the error in the faulty sentence 有人认为，过年觉得没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系?

I'm starting to feel like the error lies in 年味逐年冷淡.  It seems after 逐年, we usually add a verb (like 逐年减少, 逐年上升, 逐年恶化, 逐年扩大), and not an adjective.  It looks like it should say 年味越来越冷淡 or 年味逐年冷淡下来.

Comment: Maybe 也许 not match 很大。

Comment: A redundance: 认为 and 觉得, the latter shall be removed; a mismatch: 年味 vs 冷淡, the latter shall be changed to 变淡，for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only thing wrong in this sentence is the subject is ambiguous

It can be:

- 有人认为，过年(他们)觉得没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系。--> only the observers feel new years become less and less interesting
- 有人认为，(人们)过年觉得没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系。--> The observers concluded everyone feels new years become less and less interesting

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of 觉得:

有人认为，过年没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系。

Answer (score 1):

I think this sentence requires a preposition(介词/虚词) in front of, to modify, the phrase "过年觉得没意思":

- 有人认为，**對**(於)过年觉得没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系。- Some people believe/consider that the (people's) lack of interest in the New Year celebration may have much to do with the gradual loss of cheeriness over the years.

Answer (score 1):

People will say

(1) 有人认为，过年觉得没意思**跟**年味逐年冷淡**有**关系. Use neither 也许 nor 很大.

(2) 有人认为，过年觉得没意思**也许跟**年味逐年冷淡**有一些**关系. Use 也许 with 一些 (optional).

(3) 有人认为，过年觉得没意思**一定跟**年味逐年冷淡**有很大**关系. Use 一定 (optional) and 很大.

You may not want use 也许 with 很大. (But I personally think that is Ok)

The logic is the same as in English. If you are not very sure about an issue then you will not say “very much”.

Answer (score 1):

As a native Chinese speaker, I believe that all four options are correct sentences!

Or it could be phrased more smoothly like this.
有人认为，觉得过年没意思也许跟年味逐年冷淡有很大关系。

Answer (score 0):

You use either 认为 or 觉得; because having both in the sentence would result in a redundancy as they have basically similar meaning.